# Postgres data_type modification in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

The web application I'm working on in Django ran into a bug when I attempted modifying the data type of a field(column). I got some advice to drop/delete the table which didn't end up very well. Now I'm stuck. I tried creating a new table manually but its still giving me the same error. I tried changing the name of the previous table from its models.py, but that didn't work either. The website is giving me this error, 'Server Error (500),' as it is in production mode and the debug is set to false. I've tried. 'python manage.py makemigrations,' but it says no changes. Also, 'python manage.py migrate,' but that gives an error.

[image: Error message from development server]

Comment: First, check if you have registered your application in `INSTALLED_APPS` and try to `makemigrations`. Also check if the Postgres is connected in the project itself. There is very little information to help you in any way.

Comment: Yes, I have done that.